# Git: Resolving merge conflicts of selective files in a PR

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a pull request where four developers are working together in same branch. It's a very big PR having lot of files changes. I have contributed to some files and i want to resolve conflicts only of those files and leave rest files as it is with conflicts so that other developers can also resolve for their files. 
**So my question is can i resolve merge conflicts selectively?**

Comment: Conflicts between what and what?

Comment: I want to back merge my branch with master now. So it's my_branch and master.